# Recruit Two Historians by the End of June

Tags: discussion, pledges

So I know of at least two friends who are historians, one with a bachelor's degree and another who is a graduate student currently studying the development of socialism throughout the twentieth century.  It is my goal to introduce them to history.SE and hopefully recruit them as members for the site.

If you would like to take part in this, feel free to answer this post with your progress in recruiting (preferably professional) historians by the end of this June.

Comment: Great idea, and good luck!

Comment: Good luck, though I wouldn't be so optimistic: I guess most users would have already brought here people if they could.

Comment: If I count myself I am already +1  :)  Good luck though, site promotion is always good.

Comment: Although I've been a computer programmer for over 20 years, my college degree was a History/Political Science double major (earned over 30 years ago). Just don't ask me about the history of the 1970's.

Comment: any luck so far @BrotherJack?

Comment: I'm still rooting for you. You convince your friends?

Comment: Great idea and good luck BrotherJack. I would just add that I feel that even more important than recruiting historians, is recruiting people interested in history that will ask good questions (as separate entry here suggests). Without "poaching" them from other content and satisfied online communities, we could benefit a lot from getting new members to the community who feel confident leaving their questions our hands. It is harder for us than most since a much more narrow range of questions are welcome at SE sites so we'll have to work extra hard.